# How to activate IHubContext service in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have used signalR in my project. There is a hub that users can send notifications to each other. In login part of the project, I want to send notification to the admin when a user is signed in. I need to send this notification from controller, not client side. I tried:

```
//after dependancy injection
_hubContext.Clients.User(***).SendAsync("LoginIn", "text1", "text2", "text3");
```

The following error is shown:

> `InvalidOperationException`: Unable to resolve service for type
> '`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`' while attempting to
> activate '`CustomizedIdentity.Controllers.HomeController`'.

I tried to register IHubContext in Services:

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IHubContext<MessageHub>>();
```

But it does not work.

**Update:**

```
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
private readonly INotificationRepository _notificationRepository;
private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;
    
public HomeController(
    UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
    IUserRepository userRepository,
    INotificationRepository notificationRepository,
    IHubContext hubContext
)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
    _hubContext = hubContext;
}
```

Comment: Show us your `HomeController` constructor definition.

Comment: `builder.Services.AddScoped<IHubContext<MessageHub>>();` <-- I'm surprised this even compiles. This is not how you're supposed to register `IHubContext`. Don't you have `services.AddSignalR()` anywhere?

Comment: `services.AddSignalR()` exists. I have it already. But, the error is shown.

Comment: Change `IHubContext hubContext)` to `IHubContext<MessageHub> msgHubContext)`

Answer (score 0):

@Dai solved this problem. I must change `IHubContext hubContext` to `IHubContext<MessageHub> msgHubContext`